# OOM-killer is invoked for no reason Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ram, swap, kvm-virtualization, memory-usage, kill

I seem to be having a strange problem with oom killing processes for no reason. This is an Ubuntu 16.04 machine which is up to date, with kernel  4.4.0-62-generic and running 3 VMs and BackupPC with 16GB RAM (the machine is a dell t20). The VMs use 256MB, 2GB and 3GB RAM. Ubuntu is mostly set with default settings. The major changes after default install were installation of qemu and backuppc afaik.

```
[    0.000000] Memory: 16298836K/16683092K available (8436K kernel code, 1291K rwdata, 3960K rodata, 1488K init, 1316K bss, 384256K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
```

The release info:

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

The overcommit settings are default as follos:

```
vm.overcommit_kbytes = 0
vm.overcommit_memory = 0
vm.overcommit_ratio = 50
```

Now, the system is sometimes killing VM processes. I do not understand this because usually OOM kills the process using most memory.

```
[241816.503021] Killed process 3198 (qemu-system-x86) total-vm:4181796kB, anon-rss:3324684kB, file-rss:3588kB
```

The process was merely using 4GB vm and 3GB rss. In addition machine was not even swapping!

```
[241816.502934] Free swap  = 7953124kB
[241816.502935] Total swap = 8293372kB
```

Can you tell why the oom is killing processes? What am I missing? Because it looks like machine is using total less than 7GB RAM from 16GB installed

The full log is below:

```
[241816.502856] cron invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x26000c0, order=2, oom_score_adj=0
[241816.502859] cron cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
[241816.502862] CPU: 0 PID: 1035 Comm: cron Not tainted 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu
[241816.502863] Hardware name: Dell Inc. PowerEdge T20/0VD5HY, BIOS A06 01/27/2015
[241816.502864]  0000000000000286 00000000bf9ec188 ffff8800da123af0 ffffffff813f7c63
[241816.502866]  ffff8800da123cc8 ffff880405b5d400 ffff8800da123b60 ffffffff8120ad4e
[241816.502868]  0000000000000015 0000000000000000 ffff880409ac2540 ffff880407bad400
[241816.502869] Call Trace:
[241816.502873]  [<ffffffff813f7c63>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
[241816.502876]  [<ffffffff8120ad4e>] dump_header+0x5a/0x1c5
[241816.502878]  [<ffffffff81390c14>] ? apparmor_capable+0xc4/0x1b0
[241816.502881]  [<ffffffff811926c2>] oom_kill_process+0x202/0x3c0
[241816.502882]  [<ffffffff81192ae9>] out_of_memory+0x219/0x460
[241816.502884]  [<ffffffff81198a5d>] __alloc_pages_slowpath.constprop.88+0x8fd/0xa70
[241816.502886]  [<ffffffff81198e56>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x286/0x2a0
[241816.502887]  [<ffffffff81198f0b>] alloc_kmem_pages_node+0x4b/0xc0
[241816.502890]  [<ffffffff8107ea5e>] copy_process+0x1be/0x1b70
[241816.502891]  [<ffffffff81213d73>] ? cp_new_stat+0x153/0x180
[241816.502893]  [<ffffffff810805a0>] _do_fork+0x80/0x360
[241816.502894]  [<ffffffff81080929>] SyS_clone+0x19/0x20
[241816.502897]  [<ffffffff818385f2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
[241816.502898] Mem-Info:
[241816.502900] active_anon:1077377 inactive_anon:526767 isolated_anon:0
                 active_file:832229 inactive_file:670439 isolated_file:0
                 unevictable:914 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
                 slab_reclaimable:870324 slab_unreclaimable:29718
                 mapped:5481 shmem:5279 pagetables:5271 bounce:0
                 free:46803 free_pcp:0 free_cma:0
[241816.502902] Node 0 DMA free:15852kB min:64kB low:80kB high:96kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15936kB managed:15852kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
[241816.502905] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 3376 15901 15901 15901
[241816.502907] Node 0 DMA32 free:85128kB min:14336kB low:17920kB high:21504kB active_anon:633984kB inactive_anon:650080kB active_file:994428kB inactive_file:726700kB unevictable:56kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:3578388kB managed:3497768kB mlocked:56kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:9292kB shmem:12084kB slab_reclaimable:366052kB slab_unreclaimable:21320kB kernel_stack:1584kB pagetables:4008kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
[241816.502909] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 12524 12524 12524
[241816.502911] Node 0 Normal free:86232kB min:53180kB low:66472kB high:79768kB active_anon:3675524kB inactive_anon:1456988kB active_file:2334488kB inactive_file:1955056kB unevictable:3600kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:13088768kB managed:12825312kB mlocked:3600kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:12632kB shmem:9032kB slab_reclaimable:3115244kB slab_unreclaimable:97552kB kernel_stack:2640kB pagetables:17076kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
[241816.502913] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
[241816.502915] Node 0 DMA: 1*4kB (U) 1*8kB (U) 0*16kB 1*32kB (U) 1*64kB (U) 1*128kB (U) 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (M) 3*4096kB (M) = 15852kB
[241816.502921] Node 0 DMA32: 15269*4kB (UME) 3028*8kB (UE) 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 85300kB
[241816.502925] Node 0 Normal: 21214*4kB (UMEH) 28*8kB (EH) 11*16kB (H) 11*32kB (H) 4*64kB (H) 3*128kB (H) 2*256kB (H) 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 86760kB
[241816.502931] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
[241816.502931] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
[241816.502932] 1532619 total pagecache pages
[241816.502933] 24066 pages in swap cache
[241816.502934] Swap cache stats: add 757347, delete 733281, find 479805/565341
[241816.502934] Free swap  = 7953124kB
[241816.502935] Total swap = 8293372kB
[241816.502935] 4170773 pages RAM
[241816.502936] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
[241816.502936] 86040 pages reserved
[241816.502937] 0 pages cma reserved
[241816.502937] 0 pages hwpoisoned
[241816.502938] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
[241816.502941] [  397]     0   397     8819      832      20       3       36             0 systemd-journal
[241816.502942] [  435]     0   435    25742      229      17       3        0             0 lvmetad
[241816.502944] [  454]     0   454    11440      574      23       3      488         -1000 systemd-udevd
[241816.502945] [ 1020]     0  1020    68967     1031      36       3       58             0 accounts-daemon
[241816.502947] [ 1022]     0  1022     1100      317       7       3        2             0 acpid
[241816.502948] [ 1029]     0  1029     6322      605      18       3       83             0 smartd
[241816.502949] [ 1031]     0  1031     7470      190      18       3       49             0 cgmanager
[241816.502950] [ 1035]     0  1035     7252      594      21       3       40             0 cron
[241816.502951] [ 1040]     0  1040     6511      477      18       3       35             0 atd
[241816.502952] [ 1042]   107  1042    10726      580      26       3       59          -900 dbus-daemon
[241816.502953] [ 1098]     0  1098    58693      333      17       3        5             0 lxcfs
[241816.502955] [ 1100]     0  1100     7159      461      18       3       60             0 systemd-logind
[241816.502956] [ 1102]   104  1102    64099      451      28       3      213             0 rsyslogd
[241816.502957] [ 1104]     0  1104    53932     1284      29       5     1500             0 snapd
[241816.502958] [ 1189]     0  1189    16380      764      37       4      143         -1000 sshd
[241816.502959] [ 1201]     0  1201     3344       24      11       3       13             0 mdadm
[241816.502960] [ 1208]     0  1208     1306       31       9       3        0             0 iscsid
[241816.502961] [ 1209]     0  1209     1431      878       9       3        0           -17 iscsid
[241816.502963] [ 1216]     0  1216    69278      914      39       4      596             0 polkitd
[241816.502964] [ 1263]     0  1263   365148     1616     170       4     2336             0 libvirtd
[241816.502965] [ 1293]     0  1293     3985      366      13       3        0             0 agetty
[241816.502966] [ 1298]     0  1298     4868       23      14       3       41             0 irqbalance
[241816.502967] [ 1310]   116  1310    27509      654      24       3      113             0 ntpd
[241816.502968] [ 1421]   115  1421    17416     1849      37       3     2222             0 BackupPC
[241816.502969] [ 1422]   115  1422    54531    34434     112       3     9739             0 BackupPC_trashC
[241816.502970] [ 1471]     0  1471    18941      896      40       3      237             0 apache2
[241816.502972] [ 1544]     0  1544    16352      501      24       3       96             0 master
[241816.502973] [ 1546]   114  1546    16881      469      25       3       98             0 qmgr
[241816.502974] [ 1722]   113  1722    12496      352      27       3       97             0 dnsmasq
[241816.502975] [ 1723]     0  1723    12489        1      27       3       93             0 dnsmasq
[241816.502976] [ 1800]   113  1800    12496        0      27       3       98             0 dnsmasq
[241816.502977] [ 1804]     0  1804    48439      806      52       3       13          -900 virtlogd
[241816.502978] [ 1904]   112  1904   472592   285000     721       5     7103             0 qemu-system-x86
[241816.502979] [ 1997]   112  1997   277724    85130     334       4     9316             0 qemu-system-x86
[241816.502981] [ 3198]   112  3198  1045449   832068    1880       7    14166             0 qemu-system-x86
[241816.502982] [29065]    33 29065    18941      603      39       3      243             0 apache2
[241816.502983] [29066]    33 29066    91246      692      69       3      738             0 apache2
[241816.502984] [29067]    33 29067   124032     1274      71       4      225             0 apache2
[241816.502985] [ 5735]   115  5735   295501   258925     578       4    17706             0 BackupPC_dump
[241816.502986] [ 5818]   115  5818   276492   238098     539       4    18790             0 BackupPC_dump
[241816.502988] [ 7774]   114  7774    16869     1111      24       3        0             0 pickup
[241816.502989] Out of memory: Kill process 3198 (qemu-system-x86) score 137 or sacrifice child
[241816.503021] Killed process 3198 (qemu-system-x86) total-vm:4181796kB, anon-rss:3324684kB, file-rss:3588kB
[241816.703137] virbr1: port 4(vnet2) entered disabled state
[241816.704366] device vnet2 left promiscuous mode
[241816.704367] virbr1: port 4(vnet2) entered disabled state
[241819.514670] audit: type=1400 audit(1487210104.861:50): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" profile="unconfined" name="libvirt-c0ed3084-e7d5-4165-b125-8089914fe680" pid=8265 comm="apparmor_parser"
[247217.394936] libvirt-bin invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x26000c0, order=2, oom_score_adj=0
[247217.394938] libvirt-bin cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
[247217.394943] CPU: 1 PID: 8920 Comm: libvirt-bin Not tainted 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu
[247217.394944] Hardware name: Dell Inc. PowerEdge T20/0VD5HY, BIOS A06 01/27/2015
[247217.394945]  0000000000000286 00000000e1669350 ffff88017aaffaf0 ffffffff813f7c63
[247217.394947]  ffff88017aaffcc8 ffff8800da16e200 ffff88017aaffb60 ffffffff8120ad4e
[247217.394948]  0000000000000015 0000000000000000 ffff880409ac2540 ffff880407bad400
[247217.394950] Call Trace:
[247217.394954]  [<ffffffff813f7c63>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
[247217.394957]  [<ffffffff8120ad4e>] dump_header+0x5a/0x1c5
[247217.394960]  [<ffffffff81390c14>] ? apparmor_capable+0xc4/0x1b0
[247217.394962]  [<ffffffff811926c2>] oom_kill_process+0x202/0x3c0
[247217.394964]  [<ffffffff8119208e>] ? oom_unkillable_task+0x9e/0xd0
[247217.394965]  [<ffffffff81192ae9>] out_of_memory+0x219/0x460
[247217.394967]  [<ffffffff81198a5d>] __alloc_pages_slowpath.constprop.88+0x8fd/0xa70
[247217.394969]  [<ffffffff81198e56>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x286/0x2a0
[247217.394971]  [<ffffffff81198f0b>] alloc_kmem_pages_node+0x4b/0xc0
[247217.394974]  [<ffffffff8107ea5e>] copy_process+0x1be/0x1b70
[247217.394976]  [<ffffffff811c1660>] ? handle_mm_fault+0xce0/0x1820
[247217.394979]  [<ffffffff81037eb9>] ? sched_clock+0x9/0x10
[247217.394982]  [<ffffffff810b1bcf>] ? sched_clock_cpu+0x8f/0xa0
[247217.394984]  [<ffffffff810805a0>] _do_fork+0x80/0x360
[247217.394985]  [<ffffffff81080929>] SyS_clone+0x19/0x20
[247217.394988]  [<ffffffff818385f2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
[247217.394989] Mem-Info:
[247217.394992] active_anon:495436 inactive_anon:332110 isolated_anon:0
                 active_file:1362581 inactive_file:834329 isolated_file:0
                 unevictable:914 dirty:5499 writeback:274 unstable:0
                 slab_reclaimable:959199 slab_unreclaimable:17954
                 mapped:6609 shmem:5247 pagetables:3469 bounce:0
                 free:58696 free_pcp:115 free_cma:0
[247217.394994] Node 0 DMA free:15852kB min:64kB low:80kB high:96kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15936kB managed:15852kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
[247217.394997] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 3376 15901 15901 15901
[247217.394999] Node 0 DMA32 free:91172kB min:14336kB low:17920kB high:21504kB active_anon:345184kB inactive_anon:361348kB active_file:1469732kB inactive_file:782520kB unevictable:56kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:3578388kB managed:3497768kB mlocked:56kB dirty:3892kB writeback:220kB mapped:11244kB shmem:12080kB slab_reclaimable:422984kB slab_unreclaimable:12256kB kernel_stack:1616kB pagetables:2184kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:216 all_unreclaimable? no
[247217.395002] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 12524 12524 12524
[247217.395004] Node 0 Normal free:127760kB min:53180kB low:66472kB high:79768kB active_anon:1636560kB inactive_anon:967092kB active_file:3980592kB inactive_file:2554796kB unevictable:3600kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:13088768kB managed:12825312kB mlocked:3600kB dirty:18104kB writeback:876kB mapped:15192kB shmem:8908kB slab_reclaimable:3413812kB slab_unreclaimable:59560kB kernel_stack:2592kB pagetables:11692kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:460kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
[247217.395006] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
[247217.395008] Node 0 DMA: 1*4kB (U) 1*8kB (U) 0*16kB 1*32kB (U) 1*64kB (U) 1*128kB (U) 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (M) 3*4096kB (M) = 15852kB
[247217.395014] Node 0 DMA32: 11405*4kB (UME) 5706*8kB (UME) 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 91268kB
[247217.395018] Node 0 Normal: 30930*4kB (UMEH) 264*8kB (UMEH) 5*16kB (H) 5*32kB (H) 4*64kB (H) 3*128kB (H) 2*256kB (H) 1*512kB (H) 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 127736kB
[247217.395025] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
[247217.395025] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
[247217.395026] 2234245 total pagecache pages
[247217.395027] 31364 pages in swap cache
[247217.395028] Swap cache stats: add 769200, delete 737836, find 501629/589327
[247217.395029] Free swap  = 7999552kB
[247217.395029] Total swap = 8293372kB
[247217.395030] 4170773 pages RAM
[247217.395030] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
[247217.395031] 86040 pages reserved
[247217.395031] 0 pages cma reserved
[247217.395032] 0 pages hwpoisoned
[247217.395032] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
[247217.395040] [  397]     0   397    10970     2059      23       3       31             0 systemd-journal
[247217.395041] [  435]     0   435    25742      229      17       3        0             0 lvmetad
[247217.395044] [  454]     0   454    11440      823      23       3      396         -1000 systemd-udevd
[247217.395046] [ 1020]     0  1020    68967     1031      36       3       58             0 accounts-daemon
[247217.395047] [ 1022]     0  1022     1100      317       7       3        2             0 acpid
[247217.395048] [ 1029]     0  1029     6322      605      18       3       83             0 smartd
[247217.395050] [ 1031]     0  1031     7470      190      18       3       49             0 cgmanager
[247217.395051] [ 1035]     0  1035     7252      593      21       3       41             0 cron
[247217.395053] [ 1040]     0  1040     6511      477      18       3       35             0 atd
[247217.395054] [ 1042]   107  1042    10726      580      26       3       59          -900 dbus-daemon
[247217.395055] [ 1098]     0  1098    58693      333      17       3        5             0 lxcfs
[247217.395057] [ 1100]     0  1100     7159      461      18       3       60             0 systemd-logind
[247217.395058] [ 1102]   104  1102    64099      510      28       3      203             0 rsyslogd
[247217.395060] [ 1104]     0  1104    53932     1284      29       5     1500             0 snapd
[247217.395061] [ 1189]     0  1189    16380      764      37       4      143         -1000 sshd
[247217.395063] [ 1201]     0  1201     3344       24      11       3       13             0 mdadm
[247217.395064] [ 1208]     0  1208     1306       31       9       3        0             0 iscsid
[247217.395065] [ 1209]     0  1209     1431      878       9       3        0           -17 iscsid
[247217.395066] [ 1216]     0  1216    69278      914      39       4      596             0 polkitd
[247217.395068] [ 1263]     0  1263   365148     2482     170       4     2162             0 libvirtd
[247217.395069] [ 1293]     0  1293     3985      366      13       3        0             0 agetty
[247217.395070] [ 1298]     0  1298     4868       23      14       3       41             0 irqbalance
[247217.395072] [ 1310]   116  1310    27509      654      24       3      113             0 ntpd
[247217.395073] [ 1421]   115  1421    17416     1864      37       3     2207             0 BackupPC
[247217.395075] [ 1422]   115  1422    54531    34425     112       3     9748             0 BackupPC_trashC
[247217.395076] [ 1471]     0  1471    18941      896      40       3      237             0 apache2
[247217.395077] [ 1544]     0  1544    16352      504      24       3       93             0 master
[247217.395078] [ 1546]   114  1546    16881      469      25       3       98             0 qmgr
[247217.395080] [ 1722]   113  1722    12496      352      27       3       97             0 dnsmasq
[247217.395081] [ 1723]     0  1723    12489        1      27       3       93             0 dnsmasq
[247217.395082] [ 1800]   113  1800    12496      419      27       3       95             0 dnsmasq
[247217.395083] [ 1804]     0  1804    48439      815      52       3       11          -900 virtlogd
[247217.395085] [ 1904]   112  1904   472592   285001     721       5     7102             0 qemu-system-x86
[247217.395086] [ 1997]   112  1997   277724    85130     334       4     9316             0 qemu-system-x86
[247217.395088] [29065]    33 29065    18941      603      39       3      243             0 apache2
[247217.395090] [29066]    33 29066    91246      691      69       3      739             0 apache2
[247217.395091] [29067]    33 29067   124032     1274      71       4      225             0 apache2
[247217.395092] [ 5735]   115  5735   295501   269817     578       4     6814             0 BackupPC_dump
[247217.395094] [ 5818]   115  5818   276492   247915     539       4     9138             0 BackupPC_dump
[247217.395095] [ 8764]   114  8764    16869     1113      25       3        0             0 pickup
[247217.395097] [ 8867]     0  8867    12555      709      30       3       11             0 cron
[247217.395098] [ 8870]     0  8870     1127      189       8       3        0             0 sh
[247217.395099] [ 8871]     0  8871     1092      165       8       3        0             0 run-parts
[247217.395101] [ 8887]     0  8887     1127      441       8       3        0             0 libvirt-bin
[247217.395102] [ 8920]     0  8920     1127       27       8       3        0             0 libvirt-bin
[247217.395103] Out of memory: Kill process 1904 (qemu-system-x86) score 47 or sacrifice child
[247217.395137] Killed process 1904 (qemu-system-x86) total-vm:1890368kB, anon-rss:1136532kB, file-rss:3472kB
[247217.472809] virbr1: port 2(vnet0) entered disabled state
[247217.474014] device vnet0 left promiscuous mode
[247217.474015] virbr1: port 2(vnet0) entered disabled state
```

I am also seeing the following messages at boot. I am not sure if they are related.

```
[    0.000000] mtrr_cleanup: can not find optimal value
[    0.000000] please specify mtrr_gran_size/mtrr_chunk_size
```

In addition few memory ECC errors were logged in BIOS. But they were from months ago. We changed the whole machine to a new same model hardware machine now. Upgraded BIOS to latest version. So far the memory usage floats around less than half of the memory of the machine. We will see in a short while if OOM would kill processes again or not. It usually took a week or so...

```
KiB Mem : 16338936 total,   173348 free,  6812676 used,  9352912 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  8293372 total,  7672968 free,   620404 used.  9059716 avail Mem
```

**UPDATE:** The machine has been running perfectly for now! So the problem was probably related to the ECC errors I saw in the system OR the BIOS update fixed it. I am not 100% sure, because the whole box was replaced with another same model machine and BIOS was upgraded. So far so good!

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to post this as an answer. I don't have the rep in "AskUbuntu" to post a comment and I came here to post the same problem.

I have a very similar setup to you (16.04.2 LTS, 4.4.0-62-generic kernel) and am experiencing the same problem. I noticed the problem started about 5 days ago and it has been escalating. Today oom-killer killed 4 processes and my current system memory utilization is down to 650MB since there's almost nothing left running.

I am going to update the kernel and reboot the system and I'll report back on whether it resolved the issue.

Comment: If it makes any difference, I found some entries in dmesg at boot about mtrr. I added them to the end of my post. Do you also have something like that?
We also updated the bios to latest version now. New bios disabled some buggy intel cpu features (rtm, hle). I will try to get rid of the mtrr messages tomorrow. Have to check the bios settings. I found some threads which mention disabling some memory mapping solves it.
The problem is that I have 3 other machines 2 with 8GB and another with 16GB RAM running some VMs and they work perfectly. Backuppc uses maybe 2GB-3GB

Comment: I only have logs fro my last 2 reboots. Neither of them show the mtrr message you are receiving.  `kern.log:Feb 20 18:17:39 saffron kernel: [    0.000000] Found optimal setting for mtrr clean up`

Comment: Yesterday I updated the kernel to 4.4.0-63-generic and rebooted. System is currently at about 8 (of 16) GB of memory utilization. Reviewing my logs shows there was a 13 day gap between the last reboot and when the issue started. I'll continue to monitor and check back in in a few days.

Comment: By the way, I also saw some ECC errors in the server's BIOS logs and in dmesg but we now changed to another Dell T20 which has no errors logged. It has been up for 2 days now.